# How to calcuate base resistance from BJT circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

[image]

How do I approach this question?

My attempt:

$$I_{C} = 1mA$$

$$I_{B} = \frac {I_{C}} {\beta} $$

$$10 - I_{B}R_{B} - 0.7 = 0 $$

$$R_{B} = \frac{\beta (10 - 0.7)}{I_{C}}$$

$$R_{B} = 930 k\Omega$$

The answer should be \$R_{B} = 186.3 k\Omega\$

Comment: You are on the right track.  What is the voltage across the collector resistor? Use that to determine the collector current.

Comment: I got the correct answer now. Why is the calculated collector current used instead of the given \$1mA\$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following includes ***all*** of the elements you were asked to achieve, including make adjustments on \$V_{BE}\$ because of the higher collector current than the nominal value given. It's implied by the question, I suspect, that you need to adjust the \$700\:\textrm{mV}\$ figure.

$$\begin{align*}
I_C&=\frac{10\:\textrm{V}-5\:\textrm{V}}{1\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\\\\
&= 5\:\textrm{mA}\\\\
I_B&= \frac{I_C}{\beta}\\\\
&= 50\:\mu\textrm{A}\\\\
V_{BE}&\approx 700\:\textrm{mV} + 26\:\textrm{mV}\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{5\:\textrm{mA}}{1\:\textrm{mA}}\right)\\\\
&\approx 742\:\textrm{mV}\\\\
R_B&=\frac{10\:\textrm{V}-V_{BE}}{I_B}\\\\
&\approx 185.2\:\textrm{k}\Omega
\end{align*}$$

However, this doesn't agree with the answer you said is right. But there it is, anyway. By the way, \$\frac{k T}{q}\approx 26\:\textrm{mV}\$ at room temperature. That's where that number came from, above.